# wrapping mongoDB and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, architecture, uml

Is it possible to have  one abstraction class to be used my mongoDB class and mysql class. Since, in mysql we can perform the insert, update and delete statements in one function but mongodb we cannot.

Or they should have separate database abstraction layer

```
 // I can pass INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE query to this function but for monbodb I cannot 
mysql 
public function doNonQuery($sql){
        mysql_query($sql);
}

mongoDB
public function insert($tableName,$query){
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db,$tableName);
    $a  = $query
    $collection->insert($a);
}

public function update($tableName,$query){
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db,$tableName);
    $a  = $query
    $collection->update($a);
}
```

Comment: how are you planning to translate SQL to the MongoDB notation?

Comment: what do you mean? the mongodb query will be passed as parameter

Comment: What I mean is, MySQL queries are in SQL, and mongoDB queries are not. The point of having an abstraction class is making it possible for programmers to transparently switch back-ends, without changing the code.

Comment: what do you mean by switching back ends without changing the code :O

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer

Comment: Translating SQL to object queries would be silly, but translating object queries to SQL is a possibility.

Comment: Though, it would be difficult. You'd have to account for the ability to embedded objects and the inability to perform joins in MongoDB (among other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not thinking at the right level of abstraction. Rather than trying to abstract the Insert, Update, and Delete *operations* (which is what your code sample is doing), you should be thinking about *abstracting your domain*. This will let you come up with an interface where you can insert, update, and delete objects.. for example:

```
interface IDatabaseCollection<T> where T : IDatabaseEntity
{
    void Insert(T item);
    void Update(T item);
    void Delete(T item);
}
```

Now you could implement a SQLDatabaseCollection and a MongoDatabaseCollection that both implement IDatabaseCollection.

The above is a basic example, and there are of course many other ways to do it. But it's the direction you need to start thinking in when dealing with abstractions.

In short, your abstraction is too low-level and you need to **elevate** it to make it a higher level abstraction.